# Why scanner classes in java are not in 'jav.io' package?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io, stringtokenizer

Why StringTokenizer and Scanner classes are not a part of java.io package but these belongs to java.util package?

Comment: Because neither requires IO operations. They both can operate on regular `String`s.

Comment: InputStreamReader and BufferedReader altogether can operate on regular strings int the same way.Then why it was not included in java.io package

Answer (score 1):

Because they're utility classes and not fundamental for IO in any way.

Comment: please explain it.....as java.io package is for input and output purpose then why it was not included in java.io package

Comment: They are very useful helper classes which can be used as part of IO but are not primarily IO classes, it's a sensible abstraction.  Having them in the IO package would be strange, since anybody using them for String parsing and manipulation would be mislead.